# phonegap opendatabase returns null

Tags: api, cordova

I am using phonegap and calling the opendatabase function although I am tracking alert(window.opendatabase); alerts "function(){}" the return result is null ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a ticket filed in the PhoneGap issue tracker:

http://phonegap.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20118/tickets/115-opendatabase-returns-null-in-android-22

It was resolved and pushed to the [GitHub repository](http://www.github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android) a few days ago by me :)

Try pulling the latest from GitHub, it should work for you.

Comment: I am afraid it's still not working I downloaded the latest version of phonegap from github and have't been fixed. Any other more drastic solution for me ?